# Difference between suffix-automation and Ukkonen-suffix tree

Tags: string, algorithm, dfa, suffix-tree

I have been reading Ukkonen suffix tree algorithm from below link

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ukkonens-suffix-tree-construction-part-6/

And for understanding suffix-link i found the below link

https://cp-algorithms.com/string/suffix-automaton.html

But in plain algorithm the both ukkonen suffix tree algorithm and the 
suffix automation making me confused .
I could not differentiate them from one another .

It would be very helpful to know am I making any mistake thinking 
both of the algorithm is similar or I am failing to identify their tricky
difference.

Comment: Honestly, I would say that from what I have seen so far, there is only one good available ressource to understand how suffix-trees do work: ukkonen's original paper. I worked on it a couple years ago, and honestly, all the explanations I could find on the web were misleading, while the more I wass getting in the paper, the more it made sense to me. I'd suggest you to stick to it, that's by far the best and most complete explanation you'll find.

Comment: @m.raynal ,Thanks for your suggestion.